# cannot import name 'global_policy' from 'keras.mixed_precision' since today

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was importing a Swin-Transformer like this, which used to work the last week:

pip install tfswin
from tfswin import SwinTransformerLarge224

Since today I get the following error:

"----> 3 from keras.mixed_precision import global_policy

ImportError: cannot import name 'global_policy' from 'keras.mixed_precision' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/mixed_precision/**init**.py)"

I tried pip installing those packages as well as setting global policy with set_global_policy('float 32'). Nothing seems to work. Is it likely this is going to work again tomorrow ? Im a bit time pressured because it's a master thesis and this was the first Swin import that worked for me.
TF version is 2.10.0

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it with `!pip install keras==2.9.0`.